# Solving $39x\equiv75\pmod{102}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Decide if a solution to the congruence $39x\equiv75\pmod{102}$ exists.

As $\operatorname{hcf}(39,102)=3$ we can write the congruence as $13x\equiv25\pmod{34}$. Using Euclid's algorithm gives $1=5\cdot34-13\cdot13$.

I don't get where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, $39x\equiv75\mod102\iff13x\equiv25\mod34.$

You also wrote $1=5\times34-13\times13$; that implies $1\equiv-13\times13\equiv21\times13\mod34$.

Therefore $x\equiv21\times25\equiv15\mod34$, so solutions are $x\equiv 15, 49, $ or $83\mod 102$.

Comment: Why should the solutions necessarily be expressed modulo $102$?

Comment: not necessary, but from the title I thought that's what OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling $3$ yields $\bmod 34\!:\,\ 13x\equiv 25\iff x\equiv \dfrac{25}{13}\equiv \dfrac{75}{39}\equiv \dfrac{75}5\equiv 15$ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

---

If you only need to prove that a solution *exists* then:

$$\begin{align} \exists x\!:\,\ &39x\equiv 75\!\!\!\pmod{\!102} \\
\iff \exists x,y\!:\,\ &39x - 102y=75\\
\iff\qquad\quad\  &(39,102)\mid 75,\ \ {\rm by\ \ Bezout}\\
\iff\qquad\quad\  &\qquad\quad\ 3\mid 75,\ \ {\rm by}\ \ (39,102) = 3(13,34) = 3\\
\text{The calculation above goes further, viz.}\\[.5em]
 \exists x\!:\,\ &39x\equiv 75\!\!\!\pmod{\!102} \\
\iff \exists x,y\!:\,\ &39x - 102y=75\\
\iff \exists x,y\!:\,\ &13x \,-\, 34y=25,\ \ \text{by cancelling } 3\\
  \iff\quad \exists x\!:\,\ & 13x\equiv25\!\!\!\pmod{\!34}\\
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1243751/242) for more on this connection between Bezout and  *(modular) divisibility*.

Answer (score 0):

The Bézout's relation you obtain: $5\cdot 34-13\cdot 13=1$ 
says that inverse of $13\bmod 34 $ is $-13$, so
$$13x\equiv 25\pmod{34}\iff x\equiv (-13)\cdot 25=-325\equiv 15\pmod{34}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can actually reduce even more if you know $13\equiv -21\pmod {34}$ and $25\equiv -9\pmod {34}$ then you get:

$$-7x\equiv-3\pmod{34}$$ on division by 3, then $$7\cdot 5\equiv 1\pmod {34}\implies -7\cdot 5\equiv -1\pmod{34}$$$$\implies -7\cdot 15\equiv -3\pmod{34}$$